# Cannot access test.py file from GitHub repository using PyCharm

Tags: python, github, pycharm

I'm attempting to connect my PyCharm with my new Git-Hub account, but something peculiar is happening where the sub-file in the repository folder is not accessible in my PyCharm IDE.

The test repository can be found here:
[test.py](https://github.com/tscheer100/demopygit)

but when I try to access it using PyCharm, the folder appears, but the test.py file does not appear.

[image]

I've looked online for an answer but I couldn't find any reason why this is happening.

your help is appreciated :)

Comment: Is the file visible when you look for it from the command line / file manager?

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/526891145733603339/670771761075454043/unknown.png

Comment: In that case, are you sure your local and github repository are in sync? Maybe you missed a git pull?

Comment: I've deleted the folder locally and re-downloaded it many times from github and it still for whatever reason doesnt want to show the test.py file.

i'm using this video for reference.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBLONzkmReE&list=PLsyeobzWxl7poL9JTVyndKe62ieoN-MZ3&index=77

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

So, turns out I'm an idiot. tried it one more time and noticed an error in the events log.

I just didn't have git installed. lol

seen here:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/526891145733603339/670779689085829149/unknown.png